# Excel VBA: Copy rows from another workbook, but just the function results

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy 10 rows from a workbook into a new workbook. The copy & paste is fine, but in the copied cells are some formulas that I need to replace with the results.

Is there a magical way to copy only the displayed values from the cells?

This is how I do it now:

```
Rows("2:11").Select
Selection.Copy
myWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
ActiveSheet.Rows("1:10").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Rows("2:11").Copy
myWorkbook.WorkSheets(1).Rows("1:10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```